# JavaScript Function That Reverses Name Not Working Correctly (example from Learning JavaScript - O'Reilly)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, nested-function

I'm learning some JavaScript through Ethan Brown's "Learning JavaScript" book, and I've stumbled upon an example that doesn't perform as expected and I can't seem to figure out what the error is. I'm sure it's something obvious, I'm only on day 2 of learning this stuff but this is frustrating!

The section the code is from focuses on using the `this` keyword, and this example is supposed to show the correct way to use `this` in a nested function.

Here is the code (taken from the book, but I used my name instead of "Julie"!):

***NOTE this book focuses on ES6, not ES5***

```
const o = {
   name: "Daniel",
   greetBackwards: function() {
      const self = this;
      function getReversedName() {
         let nameBackwards = "";
         for (let i = self.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            nameBackwards += self.name[i];
         }
         return nameBackwards;
      }
      return `${getReversedName()} si eman ym , olleH`;
   },
};
```

Expected output:

> o.greetBackwards();
>
> "leinaD si eman ym , olleH"

Actual output:

> o.greetBackwards();
>
> " si eman ym , olleH"

Comment: Side note: That string reversing function is sub-optimal, as it reassigned the whole string every loop because JavaScript strings are immutable. Would be better to use `.split('').reverse().join('')`.

Comment: "Expected" --- what your expectation is based on?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara how your suggestion is better than their code?

Comment: @zerkms my expectation is based on the fact that the name property is supposed to be reversed, thus Daniel becomes leinaD

Comment: @Daniel.Schroeder "is supposed" by what? The code does exactly what it is designed for. Why do you expect to do something else?

Comment: Typo: `self.length` -> `self.name.length`

Comment: @zerkms I would replace the entire body of the `getReversedName` function with: `return self.name.split('').reverse().join('');` Then the string does not need to be reassigned every loop. For small strings it's not that bad though.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara indeed, but the provided "sub-optimal" solution would in fact be faster and make less allocations. "Then the string does not need to be reassigned every loop" --- that's not a problem at all. Being a frequent operation it's extremely well optimised in the modern engines.

Comment: @zerkms Not necessarily, but tiny strings like this are difficult to benchmark. The difference becomes prevalent with larger strings. Unless there have been some recent changes anyhow.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara you're operating with assumptions, try to profile both to know for sure.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I tried both, in cases between 10 and 10k characters string long the difference between the two is in average (at least) 3x, with a loop as a winner. So....... ;-)

Comment: @zerkms My results are much-less consistent on that. Looks like you only tested Chome/V8? It does appear JS engines are better at this than when I last tested them though.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara yep, guilty. I just personally treat it as a baseline.

Comment: @zerkms I will concede, it does appear to be better overall now. Must be some changes in the last 2 years or so. The difference is really a micro-optimization though unless your data is big.

Comment: I hope you'll learn about arrow functions soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
for (let i = self.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Should be:

```
for (let i = self.name.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

As `self` refers to the object `o`. If you want the name, it has to be `self.name`.

**Edit**: You can implement the entire `getReversedName` function with:

```
return [...self.name].reverse().join(''); // ES6 spread operator
```

Comment: Oh man, been staring at the screen too long today it appears! Thanks, I'll accept this answer in 9 mins, StackOverflow won't allow me to before that...

Comment: No problem! Glad to help :)

Comment: The latter es2015 solution with iterator is currently the only one among of provided that would work fine with 4 byte characters.